# How can I print the rows of a 2D-array in one line?

Tags: python, sys

I need to print a 2D array like `[[A,B],[C,D]]` like `A B C D`.

I've seen lots of ways to print a 1D array using `''.join()` but nothing for 2d arrays.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to "flatten" your 2D array into a 1D list, and then can use the approach you already mentioned (`' '.join(mylist)`). Without resorting to libraries like Numpy, flattening is most easily achieved using [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from the built-in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module:

```
import itertools as it

x = [['a','b'],['c','d']]

print(' '.join(it.chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

Comment: Ah, yea, reshaping didn't even occur to me.  Great, thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you don't want to reshape, you will have to use a (nested) loop. But I think reshaping is more "Pythonic".